# How to separate source files per test type in an Android library project?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, source-sets, android-sourcesets

I was following the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_test_type_source_files) to separate source files per test type in a Java project and I wanted to do the same thing in an Android library project. By default Android plugin `com.android.library` supports two types of test directories `test` and `androidTest`. How do I add say `integTest` which I wanted to run after `test`?

```
sourceSets {
     integTest {
         java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
         resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
     }
}
```

When I try to add the above `sourceSet` to the `build.gradle`, I get the error

> ERROR: The SourceSet 'integTest' is not recognized by the Android
>   Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?

Since Android Gradle Plugin doesn't support custom `sourceSets` like Java Plugin, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: `androidTest.setRoot('integTest')`

Comment: Doesn't that look for test files only in `integTest` folder? From the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#configure-sourcesets) 
`If all the files for a source set are located under a single root directory, you can specify that directory using the setRoot property. When gathering sources for the source set, Gradle looks only in locations relative to the root directory you specify. For example, after applying the configuration below for the androidTest source set, Gradle looks for Java sources only in the src/tests/java/ directory.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for the error is defining the `sourceSet` for `integTest` inside `android`, just moving it outside solved the issue. See below for correct `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integTest(type: Test) {
    group = LifecycleBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integTest

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    integTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create the same `integTest` task which will run android(instrumentation) tests from custom named sourceSet ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, can you give an example?